# Setting up a private domain for Swisscom Cloudfoundry

Tags: dns, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

most domain providers don’t allow setting a CNAME record for a main domain. It’s usually only possible to set CNAME records for subdomains.
So now I’m wondering if it would be possible to set an A record instead, pointing to scapp.io’s IP address. I tried it yesterday and it seems to work great but I’m worried that IP address might not be stable.

Any ideas whether setting an A record to 194.209.246.110 is a valid option for configuring a "naked" domain?

Answer (score 1):

**We don't recommend A record to IP address**. The IP addresses may change without prior announcement.

See [docs.developer.swisscom.com -> DNS for Domains](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#domains-dns) for other options than CNAME.

> Configuring DNS for Your Registered Root Domain
>
> To use your root domain (for example, example.com) for apps on App
>   Cloud you can either use custom DNS record types like ALIAS and ANAME,
>   if your DNS provider offers them, or subdomain redirection.
>
> *Note: Root domains are also called zone apex domains.*
>
> If your DNS provider supports using an ALIAS or ANAME record,
>   configure your root domain with your DNS provider to point at a shared
>   domain in App Cloud.

What domain provider do you use?

Comment: I’m using DomainFactory for my domain and they offer neither ALIAS nor ANAME records.

Comment: Since DomainFactory doesn't support ANAME or ALIAS records, you should use a permanent redirect for your root domain to a subdomain like "www.example.com" (i.e. subdomain redirection). I think you have two possibilities here:

1. Have some HTTP server at DomainFactory which redirects all requests to your root domain (example.com) to some subdomain (www.example.com) with a `301 Moved Permanently` HTTP status and then register a CNAME entry which points from "www" to "myapp.scapp.io"
2. Use a subdomain for your app (e.g. www.example.com)